# Android : composer screen with text edit feature like Bold change font size

Tags: android

can any body tell me how to create composer screen with some specific requirement,  like in my  composer screen I want to add feature like Bold, underline and italic for text typed.

Also font change(color and size) for the text in composer screen in android.
I want to save composer in HTML format.

please give me sample code if any body have?

thx.